# How can i calculate correctly the values of input using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get the results that i want to. After the user gives the numbers in the fields, i calculate using a formula and i stored the result in the `totalValue`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#calculateBoiler').click(function() {

        // Get Rooms Area Value

        function getRoomsArea () {
            var roomsArea = jQuery("#roomsarea").val()
            var roomsAreaNew = parseInt(roomsArea).toFixed(1);
            console.log(roomsAreaNew);
            return roomsAreaNew;
        }

        // Get RoomsHeight Value

        function getRoomsHeight () {
            var roomsHeight = jQuery("#roomsheight").val();
            var roomsHeightNew = parseInt(roomsHeight).toFixed(1);
            console.log(roomsHeightNew);
            return roomsHeightNew;
        }


        // Get Typos Ktitiou Value 

         function getBuildingType() {
             var buildtypeVal =  jQuery('input[name=selectedbuilding]:checked').val();
             console.log(buildtypeVal);
             return buildtypeVal;
        }

       // Get Zesto Nero Value

         function getHotWater() {
             var hotWaterVal =  jQuery('input[name=selectedwater]:checked').val();
             console.log(hotWaterVal);
             return hotWaterVal;
        }

         // Get Elaxisti Thermokrasia Perioxis

          function tempLocation() {
             var tempVal =  jQuery('input[name=selectedTemp]:checked').val();
            console.log(tempVal);
             return tempVal;
       }

        // Get Monwsh Ktiriou Value

        function getThermalInsulation() {
             var monwsh = (jQuery('#thermalinsulation :selected').val());
             console.log(monwsh);
             return monwsh;
        }

          var totalValue = (getRoomsArea () * getRoomsHeight () * 50) * (getThermalInsulation() * getBuildingType() * tempLocation()) + getHotWater();
           var result = (Math.round(totalValue / 100)).toFixed(2);
            console.log(result);


          // Calculations 


           switch (result) {

            case (totalValue == 0 || isNaN(totalValue)):
                     jQuery('#result').show();
                     jQuery('#result').html('<p style="color: red; text-align: center;">Οι τιμές δεν μπορεί να είναι κενές ή 0. Ξαναπροσπαθήστε!</p>');
             break;

             case (result <= 29000):
                      jQuery('#result').show();
                      jQuery('#result').html( '<h4> <span style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα που καταχωρήσατε προτεινόμενος λέβητας είναι  </span>  KPP20 ή PB26 </h4>' );
                      jQuery('#result').append('<img class="boiler-result" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/revo-line-min-1.png">');
                      jQuery('#result').append('<a class="nectar-button large regular result-btn" href="/revo-line"> Περισσότερα </a> ');   
             break;

             case (result > 29000 && result <= 35000):
                      jQuery('#result').show();
                      jQuery('#result').html( '<h4> <span style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα που καταχωρήσατε προτεινόμενος λέβητας είναι  </span>  KPP25 ή PB35 </h4>' );
                      jQuery('#result').append('<img class="boiler-result" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/revo-line-min-1.png">');
                      jQuery('#result').append('<a class="nectar-button large regular result-btn" href="/revo-line"> Περισσότερα </a> ');   
             break;
             case (result > 35000 && result <= 40000):
                      jQuery('#result').show();
                      jQuery('#result').html( '<h4> <span style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα που καταχωρήσατε προτεινόμενος λέβητας είναι  </span>  KPP34 ή PB35 </h4>' );
                      jQuery('#result').append('<img class="boiler-result" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/revo-line-min-1.png">');
                      jQuery('#result').append('<a class="nectar-button large regular result-btn" href="/revo-line"> Περισσότερα </a> ');   
             break;
             case (result > 40000 && result <= 45000):
                      jQuery('#result').show();
                      jQuery('#result').html( '<h4> <span style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα που καταχωρήσατε προτεινόμενος λέβητας είναι  </span>  KPP34 ή PB44 </h4>' );
                      jQuery('#result').append('<img class="boiler-result" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/revo-line-min-1.png">');
                      jQuery('#result').append('<a class="nectar-button large regular result-btn" href="/revo-line"> Περισσότερα </a> ');   
             break;
             case (result > 45000 && result <= 75000):
                      jQuery('#result').show();
                      jQuery('#result').html( '<h4> <span style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα που καταχωρήσατε προτεινόμενος λέβητας είναι  </span>  KPP62 ή PB70 </h4>' );
                      jQuery('#result').append('<img class="boiler-result" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/revo-line-min-1.png">');
                      jQuery('#result').append('<a class="nectar-button large regular result-btn" href="/revo-line"> Περισσότερα </a> ');   
             break;
             case (result > 75000 && result <= 100000):
                      jQuery('#result').show();
                      jQuery('#result').html( '<h4> <span style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα που καταχωρήσατε προτεινόμενος λέβητας είναι  </span> PB90 </h4>' );
                      jQuery('#result').append('<img class="boiler-result" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/revo-line-min-1.png">');
                      jQuery('#result').append('<a class="nectar-button large regular result-btn" href="/revo-line"> Περισσότερα </a> ');   
             break;

             default:
                     jQuery('#result').show();
                     jQuery('#result').html('<p style="color: red; text-align: center;">BOOOOO!</p>');
              break;     
           }










    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" id="boilerpowerForm" onsubmit="return false;">

 <div class="vc_column-inner">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="vc_col-sm-4">
            <label class="control-label" for="kmkPowierzchnia">Τετραγωνικά κτιρίου</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Εισάγετε τετραγωνικά π.χ. 20" name="roomsarea" class="form-control" id="roomsarea" value="132">
            <span class="input-group-addon">m²</span> 
        </div>
<label class="control-label">Τύπος κτιρίου</label>
           <li> <input type="radio"  name="selectedbuilding" value="1.00" checked> Κατοικία (21°C) </li>
           <li> <input type="radio"  name="selectedbuilding" value="0.80"> Επαγγελματικός χώρος(18°C) </li>

    </div>

    <div class="vc_col-sm-4">
        <label class="control-label">Ύψος κτιρίου</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Εισάγετε ύψος π.χ. 2.3" name="roomsheight" class="form-control" id="roomsheight" value="2.5">
            <span class="input-group-addon">m</span> 
        </div>
<label class="control-label">Ζεστό νερό χρόνος</label>
           <li> <input type="radio"  name="selectedwater" value="0.00" checked> none </li>
           <li> <input type="radio"  name="selectedwater" value="3.000"> < 200 l </li>
           <li> <input type="radio"  name="selectedwater" value="6.000"> > 200 l </li>
     </div>

<div class="vc_col-sm-4">
        <label class="control-label">Μόνωση</label>
        <div class="input-group">
                <select id="thermalinsulation" placeholder="Εισάγετε τετραγωνικά" class="form-control" name="thermalinsulation">
                        <option value="1.20">None</option>
                        <option value="1.00">5cm</option>
                        <option value="0.80">10cm</option>
                        <option value="0.70">15cm</option>
                   </select>
        </div>
<label class="control-label">Ελάχιστη εξωτερική θερμοκρασία περιοχής</label>
           <li> <input type="radio"  value="1.00" name="selectedTemp" checked>  0°C - 5°C  </li>
           <li> <input type="radio"  value="1.20" name="selectedTemp"> -5°C - 10°C </li>
           <li> <input type="radio"  value="1.30" name="selectedTemp"> -10°C - 20°C </li>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="vc_column-inner">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <div class="vc_col-sm-12">
     <a class="calc-btn" href="#" id="calculateBoiler">SELECT BOILER</a>
   </div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="vc_column-inner">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <div class="vc_col-sm-12">
    <div id="result">
         <p></p>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</form>
```

I expect output of 15.840 and i get 1584.00

Comment: You should provide the relevant HTML as well, so that your issue can be reproduced in the very least. If your issue is with parseInt, as in with parseInt(roomsArea), what is roomsArea and how do we know what the value is? If you provide some accompanying HTML that allows the problem to be reproduced, others will find it easier to help you.

Comment: Try logging out your totalValue variable. is that what you would expect it to be? We cant see your inputs etc so its difficult to assist. based on an expectation of 15.84 totalValue sb 1584 is that true?

Comment: Maybe because you divide by 100? `var result = (Math.round(totalValue / 100)).toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" id="boilerpowerForm" onsubmit="return false;">

 <div class="vc_column-inner">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="vc_col-sm-4">
            <label class="control-label" for="kmkPowierzchnia">Τετραγωνικά κτιρίου</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Εισάγετε τετραγωνικά π.χ. 20" name="roomsarea" class="form-control" id="roomsarea" value="132">
            <span class="input-group-addon">m²</span> 
        </div>
<label class="control-label">Τύπος κτιρίου</label>
           <li> <input type="radio"  name="selectedbuilding" value="1.00" checked> Κατοικία (21°C) </li>
           <li> <input type="radio"  name="selectedbuilding" value="0.80"> Επαγγελματικός χώρος(18°C) </li>

    </div>

    <div class="vc_col-sm-4">
        <label class="control-label">Ύψος κτιρίου</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Εισάγετε ύψος π.χ. 2.3" name="roomsheight" class="form-control" id="roomsheight" value="2.5">
            <span class="input-group-addon">m</span> 
        </div>
<label class="control-label">Ζεστό νερό χρόνος</label>
           <li> <input type="radio"  name="selectedwater" value="0.00" checked> none </li>
           <li> <input type="radio"  name="selectedwater" value="3.000"> < 200 l </li>
           <li> <input type="radio"  name="selectedwater" value="6.000"> > 200 l </li>
     </div>

<div class="vc_col-sm-4">
        <label class="control-label">Μόνωση</label>
        <div class="input-group">
                <select id="thermalinsulation" placeholder="Εισάγετε τετραγωνικά" class="form-control" name="thermalinsulation">
                        <option value="1.20">None</option>
                        <option value="1.00">5cm</option>
                        <option value="0.80">10cm</option>
                        <option value="0.70">15cm</option>
                   </select>
        </div>
<label class="control-label">Ελάχιστη εξωτερική θερμοκρασία περιοχής</label>
           <li> <input type="radio"  value="1.00" name="selectedTemp" checked>  0°C - 5°C  </li>
           <li> <input type="radio"  value="1.20" name="selectedTemp"> -5°C - 10°C </li>
           <li> <input type="radio"  value="1.30" name="selectedTemp"> -10°C - 20°C </li>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="vc_column-inner">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <div class="vc_col-sm-12">
     <a class="calc-btn" href="#" id="calculateBoiler">SELECT BOILER</a>
   </div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="vc_column-inner">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <div class="vc_col-sm-12">
    <div id="result">
         <p></p>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#calculateBoiler').click(function() {

        // Get Rooms Area Value

        function getRoomsArea () {
            var roomsArea = jQuery("#roomsarea").val()
            var roomsAreaNew = parseInt(roomsArea).toFixed(1);
            console.log(roomsAreaNew);
            return roomsAreaNew;
        }

        // Get RoomsHeight Value

        function getRoomsHeight () {
            var roomsHeight = jQuery("#roomsheight").val();
            var roomsHeightNew = parseInt(roomsHeight).toFixed(1);
            console.log(roomsHeightNew);
            return roomsHeightNew;
        }


        // Get Typos Ktitiou Value 

         function getBuildingType() {
             var buildtypeVal =  jQuery('input[name=selectedbuilding]:checked').val();
             console.log(buildtypeVal);
             return buildtypeVal;
        }

       // Get Zesto Nero Value

         function getHotWater() {
             var hotWaterVal =  jQuery('input[name=selectedwater]:checked').val();
             console.log(hotWaterVal);
             return hotWaterVal;
        }

         // Get Elaxisti Thermokrasia Perioxis

          function tempLocation() {
             var tempVal =  jQuery('input[name=selectedTemp]:checked').val();
            console.log(tempVal);
             return tempVal;
       }

        // Get Monwsh Ktiriou Value

        function getThermalInsulation() {
             var monwsh = (jQuery('#thermalinsulation :selected').val());
             console.log(monwsh);
             return monwsh;
        }

          var totalValue = (getRoomsArea () * getRoomsHeight () * 50) * (getThermalInsulation() * getBuildingType() * tempLocation()) + getHotWater();
           var result = (Math.round(totalValue / 100)).toFixed(2);

           result /= 100;
            console.log(result);


          // Calculations 


           switch (true) {

            case (totalValue == 0 || isNaN(totalValue)):
                     jQuery('#result').show();
                     jQuery('#result').html('<p style="color: red; text-align: center;">Οι τιμές δεν μπορεί να είναι κενές ή 0. Ξαναπροσπαθήστε!</p>');
             break;

             case (result <= 29000):
                      jQuery('#result').show();
                      jQuery('#result').html( '<h4> <span style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα που καταχωρήσατε προτεινόμενος λέβητας είναι  </span>  KPP20 ή PB26 </h4>' );
                      jQuery('#result').append('<img class="boiler-result" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/revo-line-min-1.png">');
                      jQuery('#result').append('<a class="nectar-button large regular result-btn" href="/revo-line"> Περισσότερα </a> ');   
             break;

             case (result > 29000 && result <= 35000):
                      jQuery('#result').show();
                      jQuery('#result').html( '<h4> <span style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα που καταχωρήσατε προτεινόμενος λέβητας είναι  </span>  KPP25 ή PB35 </h4>' );
                      jQuery('#result').append('<img class="boiler-result" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/revo-line-min-1.png">');
                      jQuery('#result').append('<a class="nectar-button large regular result-btn" href="/revo-line"> Περισσότερα </a> ');   
             break;
             case (result > 35000 && result <= 40000):
                      jQuery('#result').show();
                      jQuery('#result').html( '<h4> <span style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα που καταχωρήσατε προτεινόμενος λέβητας είναι  </span>  KPP34 ή PB35 </h4>' );
                      jQuery('#result').append('<img class="boiler-result" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/revo-line-min-1.png">');
                      jQuery('#result').append('<a class="nectar-button large regular result-btn" href="/revo-line"> Περισσότερα </a> ');   
             break;
             case (result > 40000 && result <= 45000):
                      jQuery('#result').show();
                      jQuery('#result').html( '<h4> <span style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα που καταχωρήσατε προτεινόμενος λέβητας είναι  </span>  KPP34 ή PB44 </h4>' );
                      jQuery('#result').append('<img class="boiler-result" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/revo-line-min-1.png">');
                      jQuery('#result').append('<a class="nectar-button large regular result-btn" href="/revo-line"> Περισσότερα </a> ');   
             break;
             case (result > 45000 && result <= 75000):
                      jQuery('#result').show();
                      jQuery('#result').html( '<h4> <span style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα που καταχωρήσατε προτεινόμενος λέβητας είναι  </span>  KPP62 ή PB70 </h4>' );
                      jQuery('#result').append('<img class="boiler-result" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/revo-line-min-1.png">');
                      jQuery('#result').append('<a class="nectar-button large regular result-btn" href="/revo-line"> Περισσότερα </a> ');   
             break;
             case (result > 75000 && result <= 100000):
                      jQuery('#result').show();
                      jQuery('#result').html( '<h4> <span style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα που καταχωρήσατε προτεινόμενος λέβητας είναι  </span> PB90 </h4>' );
                      jQuery('#result').append('<img class="boiler-result" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/revo-line-min-1.png">');
                      jQuery('#result').append('<a class="nectar-button large regular result-btn" href="/revo-line"> Περισσότερα </a> ');   
             break;

             default:
                     jQuery('#result').show();
                     jQuery('#result').html('<p style="color: red; text-align: center;">BOOOOO!</p>');
              break;     
           }










    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in switch you have to set true

```
....

   switch(true)
```

test this the above code is working fine.... :)

Comment: I don't believe, that the code works. `var roomsHeightNew = parseInt(roomsHeight).toFixed(1);` assigns a string (not a number), so that `getRoomsHeight()` returns a tring. Same for `getRoomsArea()`. And so the calculation of `getRoomsArea() * getRoomsHeight()` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look here:

```
function getRoomsHeight () {
     var roomsHeight = jQuery("#roomsheight").val();
     var roomsHeightNew = parseInt(roomsHeight).toFixed(1);
     console.log(roomsHeightNew);
     return roomsHeightNew;
}
```

`parseInt(roomsHeight).toFixed(1);` returns a string -- `toFixed()` returns always a string, because an exact rounded number (e.g. 2.1) does usually not exist. So function `getRoomsHeight()` returns a string too.

Same for `getRoomsArea()`.

Later you use:

```
 var totalValue = (getRoomsArea () * getRoomsHeight () * 50) * ...
```

The result is invalid, because you can't multiply 2 strings.

## Solution

Remove `.toFixed()` where you want numbers.